# ImportError: No module named 'dj_database_url' in pythonanywhere

Tags: django

I have used pythonanywhere to build a Django App.
In the bash console of pythonanywhere, I have installed python 3.5 and Django 2.0, and dj_database_url.

However, when I import dj_database_url in settings.py, I get the following error:

> ImportError: No module named 'dj_database_url'.

Comment: are you sure you installed it for the right version of python?

Comment: did you add it in requirments.txt and in settings.py?

Comment: Did you add it in your apps definition?

Comment: @Shinra tensei  in pythonanywhere I installer python 3.5  in my system it‘s python 2.7

Comment: @hansTheFranz   in setting.py  yes, why I need a file like requirments.txt

Comment: @guillermo chamorro  my Django project could run well in local machine and Lan， but when I upload it to pythonanywhere， it can not work.

Comment: What command did you use to install `dj_database_url` on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: in bash console， I used pip install dj_database_url

Comment: maybe you could try to use pip3 instead and see what happens

Comment: You need to specify the full Python version -- if you're using Python 3.5, then use `pip3.5` to install it.  This help page might also be useful: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you have installed dj_database_url, do you mean you have also configured your settings.py as explained [here](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/)?

If not, do it, then try this:

```
pip freeze>requirements.txt
git add .
git commit -m "whatever you want"
```

Then push your code to pythonanywhere.

If I am correct it is something like:

```
git push -u pythonanywhere master
```